# SQL Server messages

Tags: sql-server, xml

I´m looking into integrating our POS (point of sales) systems with our main database server and need some guidence on how to setup the communcation between the servers.

What is the prefered method of communicating between SQL Server asynchronously for smaller projects?
I got the "Message Broker" from google but I'm guessing thats a bit overkill.

Is creating xml files on the clients and sending them by FTP/SFTP to the master a valid option?

Clients are SQL Server Express and main server a SQL Server 2008R2.

Edit: Hope its more clear now.

Comment: There is very little detail here and there could be a million responses to this depending on so many things that are not explained here. You need to provide a lot more information for anybody to have much chance in helping here.

Comment: Sorry, hope its more clear now.

Comment: Creating xml files to send back and forth is a nightmare. Don't do that to yourself. You will have to create a ton of processes to deal with this.

Comment: Do you need this data realtime? Do you always have connection to the primary database? Could you just have the POS systems write directly to a single database? Can the central db pull data as it needs it? There is little chance that an answer is going to be found from an online forum. There are just too many possibilities and this type of thing is going to be filled with opinion.

Comment: I dont need the data in realtime. It can either be a triggered process from the client side (ie when a receipt is created) or by schedule.

Comment: Assuming you can't just read and write to the central database in the first place I would create some SSIS packages to move data around. Again this could change based on at least a thousand variables which I have no knowledge of. I would highly recommend you NOT use a trigger to send data remotely. You do not want to hang your POS while trying to do data manipulation on a remote server.

Comment: Writing directly to the primary database is not workable as the operation of the POS can not be dependent on the WAN connection.

Comment: Then either stage and batch your data with an SSIS package or have a sql job that will periodically fire and do whatever you need to do with the data.

Comment: Please also note the data to be sent is a couple of columns from one table.

Comment: Thanks, i'll look into SSIS packages.

Comment: Why isn't sending XML files recommended? For this particular project it would be more or less just one file sent and processed.

Comment: For XML you have to create the file, then you have to send it, then you have to shred it. Then take into account the extra network packets for xml. Way simpler to create an ETL process imho.

Comment: Is it possible to use ETL in this way with SQL Server Express?